# Sass variables with different value for media queries

Tags: sass, mixins

I am trying to achieve a margin variable which has a different values on mobile and desktop devices:

```
margin: $m-sm $m-lg;
```

expected behavior on mobile:

```
margin: 1rem 2rem
```

expected behavior on desktop:

```
margin: 3rem 6rem
```

Is there a mixin or any other way to achieve this? Thanks for any help...

Comment: You could set up a function that'll return a map value based on a key (viewport size), such as…`@function margin($viewport: desktop, $size: lg) { $margins: (desktop: (lg: 6rem, sm: 3rem) mobile: (lg: 2rem, sm: 1rem)); @return map-get(map-get($margins, $viewport), $size); }` and use it in your media queries with `margin: margin(desktop, lg);` for instance. Sorry for one-lining this. Happy to expand this into an answer if you find this helpful.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen that's already pretty helpful, but I don't need to specify the device. It would be great to just use the margin with the variable.

Comment: Then you'll want to look at [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) (a.k.a. CSS variables). Sass compiles to CSS before runtime, and does not know anything about the device. You can define your `--margin-lg` and `--margin-sm` in a media query and use those as `margin: var(--margin-sm) var(--margin-lg);`.